# Control MainWindow from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two Xaml files : "*MainWindow.xaml*" and "*Notification.xaml*"
In a class called "*Scheduled.cs*", I have an event that invokes a "*Notification*" window.
My code :

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate () {
    var notif = new Notification(currentTask);
    notif.Show(); //OK
    //Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    //Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost = true;
    //Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus();
});
```

I want to put my *MainWindows* int the top of the screen (Even when the app is minimized)
How can I do this in this situation ?

Comment: If the app is minimized how could it be at the top of the screen ?!

Comment: With the WindowState.Normal ?

Comment: When main window should be shown? It is not clear from your question. If you write `notif.ShowDialog()` then you can comment in and commented will be run after `Notification` closed.

Comment: Resolved. I had to call the "show()" method to make it word.